# After changing name server information, not able to receive email at my domain name's address in gmail

Tags: email, gmail, nameservers, webmail, mx-record

Recently I have changed my domain name's server information([www.unitechbd.com](http://www.unitechbd.com)). After changing name server information, I am able to visit my website and can change data without any problem. I can send mail, but I am not able to receive any mail to my inbox. It returns:

> Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain.

The error that the other server returned was:

> 550 No Such User Here

I have 50 email quota with my gmail account. Now how can I solve it? which information I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy to inform that I have found solution for this problem. For receiving mail via google server, you need to update MX Record in your server like this
    `Name/Host/Alias Time to Live (TTL*) Record Type Priority Value/Answer/Destination
    Blank or @  3600    MX                           1   ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
    Blank or @  3600    MX                           5   ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
    Blank or @  3600    MX                           5   ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
    Blank or @  3600    MX                           10   ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
    Blank or @  3600    MX                           10   ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM`

It will take to 48 hours for updating this information. After adding these information, you should delete your current MX record. Read this articles for more information https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125?hl=en.